# Automatic message "continue on next page" in all the pages (except the last)

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, page-numbering

I have critical document (aka a CV) with just two or three pages. Even when opened on screen it can look as if it has one page, because there is no clue (in the page) that the document continues.

Is there any package that can add either a "continued on next page" or an elegant arrow symbol "->" to hint that there is another page next.

I could use `fancyhdr` but it looks a complicated overkill because the exceptional page is the last one and not the first one. I want to avoid page numbering as well.

Comment: How about a mwe? Why do you feel that `fancyhdr` is complicated? You can put the text yourself using `tikz` or `background` or `eso-pic` or `wallpaper`...... `fancyhdr` is the simplest.

Comment: There's a more standard way to solve this problem: `page 1 of 3, page 2 of 3, page 3 of 3` (or just `1/3, 2/3, 3/3`). You can use the package `lastpage` to generate page numbers in this format.

Comment: @alexis, I know that is what I usually do, I didn't what to add that much noise. `->`, `->`, '\square` does the job more discretely.

Comment: Good question (**exactly** my own question). I think something like a simple '>' at the end of the first page is all I (we?) want. Did you have any luck with the answers below?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `fancyhdr`, it is not complicated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\fancypagestyle{firstpagestyle}{%
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Continued on next page $\longrightarrow$}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{regular}{%
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{LOGO}
\chead{Some}
\lhead{\thepage}
\rfoot{This is other page}%
}

\pagestyle{firstpagestyle}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-15]
  \thispagestyle{empty}  %% or regular
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tikzpagenodes`, needs 2-3 compilation runs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \draw[thick,magenta,latex-] (current page footer area.south east) -- +(-2cm,0)
             node[pos=1,anchor=east,text=blue] (a) {Continued on next page};
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \kant[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `eso-pic`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%    
    \hspace*{\textwidth}%
    \raisebox{-4\baselineskip}{%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{Continued on next page $\longrightarrow$}
}}}%
\begin{document} 
  \kant[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got there but I the continue on next page will appear in the last page as well. I didn't find a way to turn it off in the last page.

Comment: But if I put that, all will be empty. Do you mean to force a page break before the last?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I can start with `\thispagestyle{fancy}` right after `\begin{document}` and then end with `\thispage{empty}` (or something else) just before `\end{document}`. (I wonder what happens if the document ends up having one page.)

Comment: To clarify, the code you posted is not enough to have different footers in the first and second page, does it? (see my last comment). Also, I mean two or three pages (question changed).

Comment: Will your edit work for a three page document? (sorry I changed the question seeking a more general solution)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fancyhdr` coupled with `zref-lastpage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-lastpage,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\small\thepage}

\makeatletter
\fancyfoot[R]{%
  \ifnum\value{page}<\zref@extract{LastPage}{page}%
    \scriptsize\itshape Continue to next page $\to$%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\kant

\end{document}
```

As long as you don't change page numbering style in the document this will do.

Answer (score 3):

I see two further possibilities.

There is Donald Arseneau's `fwlw` (First Word Last Word) 1995 package which grabs the first and last *words* (with a suitable definition of *word*) on a page and the first *word* on the next page. A pagestyle is part of the package that will print on an odd page the first word on the following even page.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a6paper]{memoir} % or oneside
\usepackage{fwlw}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{NextWordFoot}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

There is also the 2011 `turnthepage` package which will print a continuation mark at the end of each odd page except if it is the last page.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a6paper]{memoir} % or oneside
\usepackage[english]{turnthepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{lipsum}
```

Note that the only speciality about using the `memoir` class is the `a6paper` class option which can produce a lot of pages with little text.